# Setting up a custom filter on Gmail / sync desktop contacts with Google contacts

Tags: gmail, gmail-filters

We have an awful lot of our incoming emails in Gmail going into junk. Can I set up a filter that will say: if I have previously sent emails to a person then never mark it as spam?

I'm aware that if you put them into your Google contacts they are much more likely to come into the inbox, but we all use desktop mail clients, a mixture of Mac Mail, and Thunderbird.

Alternatively, is there a way to sync the contact of Mac Mail and Thunderbird with Google contacts so that we don't get a lot of messages in the junk?